# can I inherit *everything* from pandas (methods, functions, read_csv, etc etc etc etc)

Tags: python, pandas, oop, decorator

suppose I create a class with my own custom functions.  I also want this class to inherit everything from Pandas.

```
class customClass(pandas.Dataframe):
    def my_func(x,y):
        return x+y.
```

instantiating

```
a = customClass()
```

typing "a." + tab I see I get a lot of pandas methods.  but I'm missing somet other things like read_csv.
is there a way to get that also?  the objective would to just use this custom class for everything.

Comment: This sounds like a definite [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627): `pandas` isn't a single class, and it contains a lot of functionality that shouldn't be in a single class. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: You see lots of `pandas.DataFrame` methods, which is all `a` will get. You don't "inherit" the module-level functions defined in the `pandas` module.

Comment: with the class I'm creating (customClass), it's going to eventually end up being a python package.  The goal is to only require that single package to do all work.  So either customClass having all the pandas methods, or me being able to use the pandas namespace to call my custom functions.  i,e pd.my_func

Comment: "customClass having all the pandas methods" doesn't make any more sense than "customClass having all the geometric methods". You can't have a single `.area()` because (a0 different shapes define it differently and (b) it doesn't make sense to have `circumference()` and `side_length()` on the same class. _Again_, Pandas _is not a single class_.

Comment: @semidevil _The goal is to only require that single package to do all work._ There has to be a better way to do that though, no? By the way, `customClass` should likely be named `CustomClass`.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Python tutorial](https://pythonspot.com/pandas-read-csv/)

The most important thing to notice for your specific question is that `read_csv` is *not* a method of `DataFrame`.  When you use that method, you call

```
pd.read_csv("local_file.csv")
```

not

```
my_df.read_csv("local_file.csv")
```

Your `customClass` does not include that method; it's not reasonable to supposed that your custom instance would show that as a method choice.

For your use case, you would still use `pandas.read_csv` in building a data frame of your custom class.

If you want to inherit the entire `pandas` pantheon, then you'll need to do so explicitly.   I don't recommend it.

Comment: thanks. so i'm curious...how would you inherit it explicitly?

Comment: See "multiple inheritance" and list them all.